# Check if td value has changed on reload of div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table, event-delegation

I'm attempting to detect if the state of each `td` element changes every 34 seconds.

How it currently works:

1. I have a PHP page that converts an array of data into a table
2. On the page that displays the table, I have a Js file connected that
   refreshes the div every 34 seconds
3. On refresh I'm checking each `td` element if it has changed value,
   but it's not working

Here's what I've currently put together, but the background color isn't changing:

```
setInterval(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8888/profitmanager/wp-content/plugins/football-stats/update.php'
        }).done(function(){
            $('.fbs_results').load(location.href+" .fbs_results>*","");
            $('.fbs_results table tr td').each(function(){
                var td = $(this);
                $(td).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
                    $(td).css('background-color', 'yellow');
                });
            });
        });
    }, 34000);
```

I thought it might be down to event delegation, but then I wouldn't know how to action that into my current script.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Use `MutationObserver`

Comment: @fiveelements do you have an example?

Comment: See here [An Example of MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @fiveelements would I include this in an each loop? How to target each td element? How would I convert that to jQuery? Thanks for your help man.

Comment: If you could possibly work the example you sent to work alongside what I'm trying to achieve that would be great. What I can see from the example is that it detects, sure - but how do I then do an if statement for each `td` element saying 'if it's changed, change background colour to yellow'.